# Is this the proper xpath query statement to grab the only MP3 href in this HTML string?

Tags: html, url, xpath, extract, href

I am having some trouble with an xpath query I am using in my code and thought I would throw this out there and ask the community if this query is in fact correctly formulated for its intended purpose.  As shown in the code below, I am looking to grab the only MP3 URL in the a tag's href attribute.  This entire bit of HTML is fed into xpath as a string.

the xpath query:

```
$hrefs = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'mp3')]/@href");
```

the HTML fed into the query:

```
<img class="myclass" title="mytitle" src="http://www.mydomain.com/myfolder/mypic.jpg" alt="myalt" width="552" height="414" />

[be-linked-title-info]

<a title="mytitle" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/myfolder/published/RJD2+-+SEVEN+LIGHT+YEARS+(INSTRUMENTAL).mp3">Song Name and Artist</a>

The written plain text post entry describing this music track goes here and says blah blah blah
```

Comment: You can use firebug or firepath addon for firefox to fetch the `xpath` of any element on the webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might be fine for your input, but it will match `mp3` anywhere in the `href` attribute, which is probably not what you want. A stricter approach would match only strings ending with `.mp3`. Like this:

```
//a['.mp3' = substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 
                              string-length('.mp3') + 1)]/@href
```

Comment: Is this grabbing the href value though?  And not the attribute itself?

Comment: @virtuapete - It's selecting the attribute itself. Your host language will determine what that object is. Is that PHP? If so, you might be getting back an instance of this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php

Comment: I am trying to obtain the href attribute's value, which in my case is the literal URL for the MP3... I need the URL itself to be returned from the query.  And yes this is PHP 5.3.x

Comment: @virtuapete - Your host language determines the object you get back. An attribute isn't just its value, since it clearly also has a name. See the link I posted before.